# Will disabled tasks in SSIS be validated during execution or package load

Tags: sql-server, validation, ssis, etl

Setting the `DelayValidation` will skip validation for all the tasks when loading the package if I am not wrong.

But how about if I keep the `DelayValidation` as false, will disabled tasks be validated when loading the package? What is more important, will they get validated during the pre-execution?

Comment: I don't think that disabled tasks are validated, try to create a task with errors and Disable it, then try to run the package it will run without errors. But to get a precise answer, just read the package progress it will write the validation phase for each task

Comment: Hi @Yahfoufi, could you please guide me how to read the package progress?

Comment: I think that you got a detailed answer

Comment: why accepting an answer that should be a comment and ignoring a detailed answer providing experiments??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, disabled tasks are ignored during validation.

Comment: You need to **prove** your answer. Just saying No is **not sufficient**

Answer (score 2):

## Very Simple Experiment To Prove that Disabled Tasks are not validated

1. I Created a package with 2 Execute SQL Task
2. each one of these contains SELECT statment

   ```
   SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
   ```
3. I Disabled one and leave the second enabled

[image]

4. Both `Delay Validation` Property is set to `False`
5. Execute the package , everything is working normally

[image]

6. Go to the progress Tab

[image]

7. It shows that only `Enable Execute SQL Task` is validated, and the Disabled Task is totally ignored

[image]